# Hyper-V Client for Microsoft Networks gone

Tags: networking, hyper-v, local-area-network, static-ip

[image]I have an odd situation. I have a Hyper-V Baremetal Windows 2008 x64 (not R2) host with 4 VM's on it. I also have a server next door on the lan that is not a host just Windows2003x86 called ServerS2

- HostX1....... 192.168.0.10
- - Guestv1...... 192.168.0.11
- - Guestv2...... 192.168.0.12
- - Guestv3...... 192.168.0.13
- - Guestv4...... 192.168.0.14
- ServerS2..... 192.168.0.102

For some reason the HostX1 cannot see  ANYONE elses files over the LAN. It can see the remote desktop and it can ping and it can share it's OWN files fine to the others.

There is a clue. The destination servers that HostX1 tries to windows explorer halts immediately (no spinning wait) so this makes me think.

HostX1 Client for Microsoft Networks is unticked and windows will not let me tick it (it says i am disabling it if I tick it), also HostX1 Windows2008 Network Connections->Properties is showing me that the IP's are obtained automatically but they are NOT obtained automatically they are static IP's when I ipconfig/all

can anyone help me get windows explorer "Client for Microsoft Windows" added to these 4 Network cards on Hostx1, and tell me why they are showing static IP's in IPCONFIG but have DHCP automatically set (this is impossible by the way there is no DHCP server)  how do I get it so I can see the other guys in the LAN? I tried installing "Client for Microsoft Windows" by "installing" under "networking properties" of the card but it wants a disk and I don't have one and the drivers from the broadcom card don't come as a disk anyway

Thanks

Comment: for the record this appears to be related to a disk fault and corrupted inf files. We decided upon reinstall windows host. Bad but there you go, not everything be "fixed"

Answer (score 0):

On the Hyper-v host server the only thing that should be bound to your physical nic is the "Hyper-v Extensible Switch" protocol. Not even IP should be bound to that card.

The Hyperv virtual network card is where your bindings happen.

Another thing is that the Hyper-v server is free. You may want to use the latest - Hyper-v Server 2012.

Brian

Comment: thanks, I won't use Win2012 (tried, no start button, cried, left) it's too inexplicably without a gui, and I am, decided upon upgrading the host to Win2k8R2 today